# JComboBox , How to know what specific option is selected at a time

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jframe

Hi Im currently trying to design a shopping cart for my college work, What im currently trying to do is have a comboBox and when a user clicks on a option in the comboBox information is displayed about that option the user has picked.

I've spent a while trying to look up how to do this and the advice given is to use a actionListener on the comboBox. I've added a actionListerner however im a tad stuck of the next part. Currently when the user clicks on a option for the first time it will display the text correctly however if he picks another option after that the text will stay the same. I need to find a way to keep running through my IF statements to keep checking what has been selected. I tried adding a while loop to my ActionListener however that did not seem to do the trick.

Below is the code from the Listener and also how i created the comboBox and its options.

ComboBox

golfBagOptions = new JComboBox ();

```
      golfBagOptions.addItem("TaylorMade Juggernaut Cart Bag");
      golfBagOptions.addItem("Mizuno Golf Rider Cart Bag");
      golfBagOptions.addItem("Titleist RC13 Reverse Cart Bag");
      golfBagOptions.addItem("Callaway Golf Euro Chev Org Cart Bag");
```

ActionListener

```
golfBagOptions.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            if (golfBagOptions.getSelectedItem().toString()=="TaylorMade Juggernaut Cart Bag");{
                String startNewLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                golfBagInformation.setText("Name : TaylorMade Juggernaut Cart Bag" + startNewLine + "Price: £129" + startNewLine + "Colour: Blue" + startNewLine + 
                        "Description: With powerful looks and crush-resistant construction, the TaylorMade Juggernaut Cart Bag is an intimidating and widely popular golf bag." );
            }
            if (golfBagOptions.getSelectedItem().toString()=="Mizuno Golf Rider Cart Bag");{
                String startNewLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                golfBagInformation.setText("Name : Mizuno Golf Rider Cart Bag" + startNewLine + "Price: £99.99" + startNewLine + "Colour: Black" + startNewLine + 
                        "Description: Something which is often difficult to achieve on a busy golf course is that sense of everything in its place. The Mizuno Aerolite 5 Golf Stand Bag has been created with an abundance of storage options, " +
                        "excellent golf club placement and " +
                        "reduces strain on the back when carried." );
            }
            if (golfBagOptions.getSelectedItem().toString()=="Titleist Lightweight SE Stand Bag");{
                String startNewLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                golfBagInformation.setText("Name : TaylorMade Juggernaut Cart Bag" + startNewLine + "Price: £99.99" + startNewLine + "Colour: Silver" + startNewLine + 
                        "Description: Carry your golf gear around the golf course effortlessly with the stylish Titleist Lightweight SE Stand Bag. Slip on this comfortable bag and you will be amazed by the " +
                        "lightweight comfort and convenience of a fast stand mechanism with broad foot and tripod rubber feet for ultimate stability." +
                        " The Titleist Lightweight SE Stand Bag is perfect for walking around the course in style." );
            }
            if (golfBagOptions.getSelectedItem().toString()=="Cleveland Golf Lightweight Stand Bag");{
                String startNewLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                golfBagInformation.setText("Name : TaylorMade Juggernaut Cart Bag" + startNewLine + "Price: £79.99" + startNewLine + "Colour: Blue" + startNewLine + 
                        "Description: To keep your golf clubs protected both on and off the golf course, the Cleveland Lightweight Stand Bag will assure total comfort, safety and smart construction." );
            }

        }
    });
```

If someone could please point me in the right direction, i'd very much appreciate it.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
  if (golfBagOptions.getSelectedItem().toString()=="TaylorMade Juggernaut Cart Bag");{
```

to

```
 if (((String)golfBagOptions.getSelectedItem()).equals("TaylorMade Juggernaut Cart Bag"){
```

Adjust changes to all the if conditions.

> 1 ) Remove all the semicolon from the if statements
>
> 2 ) To compare String objects in java use .equals() method instead of "=="
> operator

Comment: Thanks, can't believe it was such a easy to fix to such a mind numbing issue! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (golfBagOptions.getSelectedItem().toString()=="TaylorMade Juggernaut Cart Bag");
```

First thing is there should not be a `; semicolon` after if statement.

also instead of `==` use `equals` method.

you can make it in a more better way by use of `enums`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare with action command it may help you

```
e.getActionCommand();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just store the value of `golfBagOptions.getSelectedItem();` and then use it in your if statements.

This will reduce runtime load.